# How to remove column-duplicates from the query result using entity-framework?

Tags: entity-framework

On my database table I have

```
Key    | Value
a      | 1
a      | 2
b      | 11
c      | 1
d      | 2
b      | 3
```

But I just need to get the items which keys are not duplicates of the previous rows. The desired result should be:

```
Key    | Value
a      | 1
b      | 11
c      | 1
d      | 2
```

How could we get the desired result using entity-framework?

Note: we need the first value. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are 2 values for the key 'a' which are '1' and '2'. The first value is 1. This is based on whatever the sorting may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from e in Context.MyTable
        group e by e.Key into g
        select new 
        {
            Key = g.Key,
            Value = g.OrderBy(v => v.Value).FirstOrDefault()
        };
```

Comment: This looks great! How could we convert this to lambda if it is possible? Thanks.

Comment: Easiest way is to type it into LINQPad and let that app convert it for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at either writing a View in the database and mapping your entity to that.
Or creating a DefiningQuery in the  part of your EDMX (aka the bit that ends up in the SSDL file).

See [Tip 34](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx) for more information.

Conceptually both approaches allow you to write a view that excludes the 'duplicate rows'. The difference is just where the view lives.

If you have control over the database - I'd put the view in the database
If not you can put the view in your  inside the  and then map to that.

Hope this helps

Alex